# Android Bluetooth notification icon

Tags: android, bluetooth, icons

When enabling the Android bluetooth adapter, how can the standard bluetooth notification icon be hidden? That is the icon at the top, in the status bar.

I only need to enable to the bluetooth adapter for a very short while to retrieve the paired devices, then immediately disable the adapter, and want to stop the icon flashing.

Any help much appreciated.

tia

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. This is a system feature that provides the user with an indication that Bluetooth is enabled. The system does not care how long Bluetooth is enabled, it just needs to ensure that the user knows that Bluetooth is enabled.

Since you are enabling Bluetooth, the icon will be shown.